# Django serving each app separately in each its port

Tags: python, django, port, django-dev-server

I've got a very simple project running on Django (no models yet) and I need to do the following:

I have created 2 apps, `'Ebony'` and `'Ivory'` that need to communicate with each other through `JSON` messages (originally designed to run on different machines but for now one is good enough).

The problem is that the Django `Debug` server is just one process which runs in a specific port. What I want to do is make each `'App'` listen to its own port on the same server and if possible under the same Django project. Is such a scenario possible? And if yes, how should I go about it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is possible, but not the way you're conceptualizing it. A Django app is one part of what runs on a given web server. Thus a Django project, which has one or more apps, runs as a part of one web server.

The solution is to run multiple instances of Django. Not sure how well this is going to work for you with the debug servers. You can [run each server on its own port](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port) by giving it a parameter telling it where to open the port, for example:

```
./manage.py runserver 8000
```

runs a debug server on 127.0.0.1:8000, and

```
./manage.py runserver 8080
```

runs another debug server on 127.0.0.1:8080. Usually this is done in separate shells.

You will need to make sure that the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting on one of these has `'Ebony'` in it, and the other has `'Ivory'`. You will also need to figure out some way to tell each instance how to connect to the other (usually by specifying a root URL).

---

That said, later on you will need to figure out if your two apps will be sharing the same database. If so, make sure that both machines can get to it. If not, make sure the `DATABASES` value in `settings.py` is different for each one. If you're sharing the database, Django's [sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/sites/) can help you keep things straight in your models.

---

To have both running from the same project, you have to tell Django which one to run. I prefer to use an environment variable. This changes the above `runserver` commands to:

```
SHARD=Ebony ./manage.py runserver 8000
```

and

```
SHARD=Ivory ./manage.py runserver 8080
```

In your `settings.py` file, this variable can be accessed through `os.environ`. So, for example, for the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting to have different values for each shard, you write something like:

```
SHARD = os.environ["SHARD"]

# Apps common to all shards go here.
LOCAL_APPS = [
    commonApp,
]

# Add apps specific to each shard.
if SHARD == "Ebony":
    LOCAL_APPS += [
        Ebony,
    ]
elif SHARD == "Ivory":
    LOCAL_APPS += [
        Ivory,
    ]

# Add them to the apps that aren't mine.
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # ... omitted for brevity ...
    'django_extensions',
    'south',
    'debug_toolbar',
) + LOCAL_APPS
```

By defining `SHARD` as a setting in this file, you avoid having to have all your code access the environment variable, and you confine the logic for setting `SHARD` to `settings.py`, in case you want to change it later. Your other Python files, if needed, can get the setting with `from django.conf.settings import SHARD`.

A similar mechanism can be used to give each shard its own `DATABASES` setting, too. And anything else in `settings.py`.

Then later in your `urls.py` file, you use that to pull in your apps' URLs:

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'commonApp.views.get_homepage', name='home'),
    url(r'^login$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name="login"),
    url(r'^logout$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', 
        {"next_page": "/"}, name="logout"),
# Admin
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

# Auto-add the applications.
for app in settings.LOCAL_APPS:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^{0}/'.format(app), include(app + '.urls', namespace=app)),
    )
```

This means your apps need their own `urls.py` files, and your app URL names get prefixed with your app names. So if the app `Ebony` defines a URL pattern with `name="index"`, you would get that URL in a template with `{% url 'Ebony:index' %}`.

Comment: Great. Could you be a bit more specific on the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting part? You said that the first app has to have `Ebony` while the other has to contain `Ivory`. However I only have one settings.py file under the `Ebony` folder...

Comment: The answer to that requires details about how you want to do this. You could have two separate Django projects, one for each app, or you could have a single project on two servers.

Comment: I 'll take the second option; single project with two apps on two servers (preferably debug servers for now). I figured out how to setup the `INSTALLED_APPS` but I'm struggling with the `urls.py`. The problem is that I have no way to tell Django how to distinguish the url mappings based on a particular server instance. For example say I have the following two urls in my `urls.py`: `url(r'^Ebony/$', task1)` and `url(r'^Ivory/$', task2)`. When I do `http:127.0.0.1:80/Ebony` I need to get task1 (same for Ivory) but if I do `http:127.0.0.1:8080/Ebony` I shouldn't be getting task1.

Comment: Updated to add example of shard support, which is what you need.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent and thorough answer. This worked great!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone willing to have multiple servers or ports for the same Django app, but is actually just trying to implement a monolitic project hosting both backend and frontend for your project, a very simple solution is to **add prefixes to each "server"**, or just add a prefix for backend endpoints, like `/api/`.

Example:

`urls.py`

```
import myproject.apps.website.views.example_view as example_view
import myproject.apps.apis.v1.example_view as api_example_view
import myproject.apps.apis.v1.example_view_2 as api_example_view_2


urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls, name="admin"),
    ...
    # Docs
    path("iapi/doc/schema/", SpectacularAPIView.as_view(), name="schema"),
    ...
    # Backend
    path("api/be_page/", api_example_view.get, name="some_be_view"),
    path("api/be_page_2/<str:id>/", api_example_view_2.edit, name="some_be_view_2_edit"),
    # Frontend
    path("", example_view.get, name="root_fe_view"),
    path("fe_page/list", example_view.get, name="some_fe_view_list"),
    path("fe_page/edit/<str:id>/", example_view.edit, name="some_fe_view_edit"),
]
```