# Running apps present in same project in different ports at the same time using django

Tags: django, django-models, django-apps, django-project-architect

I am writng multiple apps inside the same django project
Now I want to run each app individually 
my project name is : myproject 
and i have 2 apps inside it : app1, app2 
Now i want to run app1 in different port(7000) and app2 in different port(7002) simultaneously. Is there any way to acheive it??

Comment: [Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325371/django-serving-each-app-separately-in-each-its-port) Its the same issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django serving each app separately in each its port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325371/django-serving-each-app-separately-in-each-its-port)

Answer (score 0):

Create different seetings.py, for each application, for example settings1 and settings2. In settings1 add app1 in `INSTALLED_APPS` and in seetings2 add app2.

Then you can run two instances of Django, but with different settings module