# Django single sign on between different ports

Tags: python, django, session, cookies, single-sign-on

Thank you for taking a look at this question.

I have 2 separate Django projects which are totally independent and host the 2 projects through nginx such as:

http://xxx.xx.x.xxx:8080/   => Django `Project A`

http://xxx.xx.x.xxx:8000/   => Django `Project B`

The 2 projects are integrated in such a way that the projects share the same user table of PostgreSQL. Each of the projects has its own login page but I can use the same login credentials to sign in.

The thing is, the 2 projects cannot share login sessions(or cookies?) with each other. So I have to sign in the `project A` first and later sign in the `project B` once more(or vice versa) with the same login information.

I've heard that I need to use SSO(Single Sign On) to solve this problem but none of solutions below was able to tackle the issue.

- django-simple-sso
- django-cas-provider/consumer
- MamaCAS
- Tried to tweak session options on settings.py (e.g. SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN)

There could be lack of my understanding of the solutions above but most of the solutions were outdated or not fit for this case.

How could I deal with this issue? Have you solved similar issues?

Comment: Please go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23325450/9526947), it might help

Comment: SSOs worki like this. After your first application successful log in the server returns a token and with that token your second application authorizes the logged in user.

Comment: @KostasCharitidis What kind of SSO solution did you use?

Comment: Follow these steps it's pretty clear. https://medium.com/@MicroPyramid/django-single-sign-on-sso-to-multiple-applications-64637da015f4

Comment: @KostasCharitidis I tried this earlier but was stuck with this [issue](https://github.com/divio/django-simple-sso/issues/37)